# cakephp 2.0 Migration: Redirect not working

Tags: cakephp, migration

This is confusing to me.  I'm manually converting my cakephp 1.3 application to 2.0 to understand it better rather.  Everything seems to be working,  but for some reason the $this->redirect() function isn't working. It just leaves me with a blank screen.

My code is:

```
class TimeslotsController extends AppController {
  var $helpers = array ('Html','Form', 'Calendar');
  var $name = 'Timeslot';
  var $uses = array('User', 'Timeslot', 'TransLog', 'Credit', 'Section', 'StudentSection', 'Assignment', 'Call') ;
  var $components = array('Calendar', 'Local', 'Email');

  function index() {
    $this->redirect('admin/user/37');
  }

 }
```

Am I missing something on how cake 2.0 handles redirects?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you wanna go with this redirect ? To the UsersController ?

Comment: why is there a `var $name = 'Timeslot';`.
a) if anything it should also be plural
b) it should be removed in 2.0 alltogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two things. Either use an absolute URL, thus starting with a / like:

```
$this->redirect('/admin/user/37');
```

Or (better way) write it in full, like:

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'admin' => true, // Requires admin routing prefix in Config/core.php
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'index',
    37
));
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is a whitespace in AppController or in PageController , it prevents header to be set , and hence redirect doesn't work.
check for white space before php code if all above syntex doesn't work